# How to add a new line before `trailing' comment in babel AST?

Tags: babeljs

Is it possible to add an extra `NewLine` before the `trailing` comment line (just like the block comment)?

My case is that,

```js
types.addComment(defaultPropsNode, "leading", "#region defaultProps", true);
types.addComment(defaultPropsNode, "trailing", "#endregion", true);
```

Output is,

```js
//#region defaultProps
static defaultProps = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
}; //#endregion
```

The `#region` directive looks like an `inner` comment, and it doesn't work in vsCode unless it's put in a new line.